# How can I turn on High Contrast mode for Firefox in my playwright tests

Tags: firefox, playwright, playwright-test, high-contrast

I am trying to setup a playwright project to run high-contrast tests for Firefox. I have a working setup for chromium in high-contrast using the following in my playwright config:

```
name: 'chromium-highContrast',
  use: {
    browserName: 'chromium',
    colorScheme: 'dark',
    contextOptions: { forcedColors: 'active' },
  }
```

Now if I try the same setup for my Firefox tests it does not work.
So for Firefox I would setup the project like this:

```
name: 'firefox-highContrast',
  use: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    colorScheme: 'dark',
    contextOptions: { forcedColors: 'active' },
  }
```

The screenshot tests still show Firefox normally while in chromium they show as high-contrast. Same for debugging.
I use Fedora 38 and playwright version 1.35.0 .

Do I need a different setup for Firefox or can I accomplish this in another way?

Edit: Added a Screenshot of the expected colors

[image: Firefox HighContrast on Windows 10]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to set this up using the following settings.

```
firefoxUserPrefs: {
         'browser.display.document_color_use': 2,
         'browser.display.use_system_colors': false,
         'ui.use_standins_for_native_colors': false,
         'ui.highlight': '#00FFFF',
         'ui.highlighttext': '#000000',
         'ui.graytext': '#00FF00',
         'ui.buttonface': '#000000',
         'browser.anchor_color': '#FFFF00',
         'browser.display.background_color': '#000000',
         'browser.display.foreground_color': '#FFFFFF',
         'browser.visited_color': '#FFFF00',
         'browser.active_color': '#FFFF00',
},
```

The playwright browser sets some additional settings which differ from my local firefox version. My result looks like this which is still a little bit off but close enough for my purposes:
[image: screenshot with firefox settings]
I use this [Website to display the current browser config](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#ex-SystemCombo)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the keys from `about:config` that can help you.

- **layout.css.prefers-color-scheme.content-override** - Website appearance
- **browser.display.document_color_use** - Colors -> Override the colors specified by the page with your selections above

```js
// playwright.config.ts

  use: {
    browserName: "firefox",
    launchOptions: {
      firefoxUserPrefs: {
        "layout.css.prefers-color-scheme.content-override": 0, // Dark
        "browser.display.document_color_use": 2, // Always
      },
    },
  }
```

And UI will look like this:

[image: settings]
and website
[image]

**UPD**:

Attached screenshot with params [image] that matches Chrome high contrast mode. Yellow links and black background

```
browser.display.background_color = #000000
browser.display.foreground_color = #ffffff
browser.display.document_color_use = 2
browser.display.use_system_colors = false
```

Comment: This just triggers a dark mode. I need to simulate high contrast mode in the tests as the application I am testing has some issues in Firefox high contrast.

Comment: it's high contrast mode, dark mode looks different. I attached FF setting screenshot

Comment: In high contrast mode I would expect the links to be yellow and the background to be just black as well as gray text to be green. I have a reference screenshot taken in the windows high contrast mode and am trying to replicate that.

Comment: I bet you have a reference from Chrome, which renders UI differently. I just checked Win 11 Night Sky contrast mode - it looks the same as the screenshot I posted. But you can always set colors you want in FF params https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-website-appearance-settings-firefox

Comment: I can see FF in the taskbar and it has the colors I described above. Although I am not sure what OS version it was taken from. Although they have the whole OS in high contrast mode as even the taskbar icon has the turquoise background.

Comment: I am already trying to replicate those colors with the FF params but I am still struggling with grayText and highlight colors.

Comment: I attached settings for coloring FF the same way Chrome does it. Even if after this you can't handle it - good luck, I'm out of it :)